# Get variable from PuppetMaster config from ruby functions

Tags: ruby, puppet

I wrote simple function for my puppet module. It makes some requests using puppetdb API and I need IP address of puppetdb server. Is there correct way to get settings of connection PuppetMaster to puppetdb to get address of puppetdb server or I should parse puppet.conf by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing `puppetdb.conf` by hand would be the least desirable way to go about it.

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetdb/blob/master/puppet/lib/puppet/util/puppetdb/config.rb#L31-47) that loads the config, it should be possible to access it using

```
settings_value = Puppet::Util::Puppetdb.config['main'][setting_name]
```

for configuration options from the `[main]` section.

Looking at [even more code](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetdb/blob/master/puppet/lib/puppet/util/puppetdb.rb#L14-20), you should even be able to use

```
Puppet::Util::Puppetdb.server
Puppet::Util::Puppetdb.port
```

I'm not entirely sure whether those APIs are available from parser functions, but it's worth a shot.